# MySQL iniciante com muita dificuldade

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, oracle, osx

Galera, queria começar a aprender `MySQL`, mas não estou conseguindo começar, não entendo os softwares nem nada, os tutoriais na web não falam sobre `MySQL` em `Mac`, apenas em `Windows`. 
Eu baixei o `MySQL` no site da Oracle e o `sequel pro`, fiz certo? Agora onde eu posso ver tutoriais que usam windows e outros softwares que da tudo na mesma? Caso não onde eu posso achar conteudo sobre o `sequel pro` e `MySQL` pra `mac`? Obrigado

Comment: o MySQL no MAC OSX funciona da mesma forma que no Linux ou Windows. No MAC OSX a instalação de software pode ser feita usando Homebrew ou baixar o executável do site da Oracle como você fez. Em ambos os casos você terá disponível no Terminal o comando mysql e mysqladmin, dentre outros. A principio você não precisa usar nenhuma interface visual como o sequel pro.  Eu sugiro que você coloque dúvidas mais específias aqui assim poderemos responde-las uma a uma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fala Alexandre, esse tutorial em slides escrito por outro Alexandre é muito intuitivo e ajudará você bastante na empreitada

http://pt.slideshare.net/alepilot/instalando-o-mysql-em-menos-de-10-minutos

após isso o melhor lugar para você dar seus primeiros passos com MySQL não tenho dúvidas que é na documentação oficial

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/

Detalhe embora já tenha o MySQL 5.7 prefira estudar o 5.5 pois atualmente é o mais largamente utilizado.

espero ter ajudado. forte abraço!